# How to make "Cast to Device" reliable in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, dlna

I have Samsung QN85BA 65 TV connected to the same LAN as my Windows computer. Sometimes I see it in "Cast to device" but sometimes not, unpredictable.

How to force it either always visible or force device scanning when I need it?

---

I don't think it is Miracast. TV is connected to the LAN bay WiFi, but the PC is connected to the LAN by wire.

Comment: Opening the "Cast to device" menu does run a full rescan, every device that responds should show up. If the TV is asleep/low-power, it might not respond in time or at all. Cast to device can also mean either dlna-style connection using the same LAN network, or Miracast/wifi-direct, which connects wirelessly from the PC to the TV (and can be range-limited)

Comment: Windows usually keeps better track of devices you've previously connected to in the Settings > Devices > Bluetooth & other devices page, even if they're not currently responding. Depending on how the TV is connected, you can usually still see it there and try to connect using the saved information.

Comment: I've never found Miracast to be particularly reliable (I think it runs over bluetooth, which I've also never found to be suitably reliable).

Comment: @Cpt.Whale is there more explicit way to call scan, rather opening some menu? Like command line or GUI with explicit indication of search?

Comment: @Dims the way these protocols work is your PC broadcasts a request (when you open a connect/cast to menu), and compatible devices reply (if they see it) with an advertisement saying what they are etc. Those advertisements expire pretty quickly, which is why it has to rescan every time. It *is* actively scanning any time you have a cast-to-device menu open.

Comment: Most of the problems with device discovery are on the TV's end, like not waking up fast enough or not responding. You may be able to update the software on the TV to improve things, but your mileage may vary

Comment: @Cpt.Whale how to see this with Wireshark?

Comment: In wireshark, most of the search/reply traffic will show up as `ssdp` for upnp/dlna requests: https://wiki.wireshark.org/SSDP.md . Miracast/WiFi direct scanning uses WPS and other stuff at the radio layer, so it doesn't capture unless you have wlan capture configured: https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN